# Connectivity of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Lets say that I have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

What does it mean if I take out one node in this case $6$ is it a valid argument to say that the graph still has $6$ edges?

[image]

Or that is it an invalid graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edges by definition connect nodes, so that is not a valid graph. Also, the first graph has 7 edges and the second has 6, not 5.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I will edit the original question.